# 301 Redirection After Comment

Tags: multisite, comments, redirect, wp-redirect

The below code redirects visitors to any page that you want.

```php
// Redirect to thank you post after comment
add_action('comment_post_redirect', 'redirect_to_thank_page');
function redirect_to_thank_page() {
    return 'https://example.com/thank-you';
}
```

However, I use WP Multisite feature and the same active theme is used by all subsites in the network. So can I redirect visitors according to the subsite which they visit?

i.e. if you leave a comment on example.com/fr, then you'll be redirected automatically to example.com/fr/thank-you page.

If we use blog-id or subdirectory name in the above snippet, it might help?

**WP Multisite method:** subdirectory

Regards.

Comment: Yes, you can use the blog_id, and add a conditional or switch.

Comment: @WebElaine Thank you for the answer, WebElaine. I've been learning Javascript for 2 months but still, I don't know PHP. Can you please help me to create that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a thank-you-page with same slug in all sites you can do:

```
add_action('comment_post_redirect', 'redirect_to_thank_page');

function redirect_to_thank_page() {
  return get_bloginfo('url').'/thank-you-page';
}
```

`get_bloginfo('url')` detects the subsite you're currently in

Comment: It makes sense! I can't thank you enough! Regards.